# Knockout JS - bind css class to an element

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend

I want to achieve dynamic class biding, which should assign and reassign correct class based on variable, putted in this field. The issue I got, when I induce function `setRed()`, and then `setWhite()`, both color classes are binded, and of course 1st CSS class is considered.

I've got an element which binding looks like that:

```
<div data-bind='dxNumberBox: dxCustomCalc'></div>
```

So far I made `elementAttr` class `ko.observable();`

```
self.dxCustomCalc = {
    displayExpr: 'Name',
    keyExpr: 'Id',
    value: self.customCalc,
    //onValueChanged: function (e) {
    //    self.childFormName(e.component.option('selectedItem'));
    //},
    disabled: ko.computed(function () {
        return self.readOnly;
    }),
    elementAttr: {
        /*   class: "is-valid-nok"*/        /* - red*/
        /*class: "is-valid-onlyok"  */    /* -white */
        /*class: "is-required-empty",*/  /* - yellow */
        class: ko.observable(),
    }
};
```

And went through element:

```
function setRed() {
    self.dxCustomCalc.elementAttr.class("is-valid-nok");
    console.log("color changed to red")
}

function setWhite(){
    self.dxCustomCalc.elementAttr.class("is-valid-onlyok");
    console.log("color changed to white")
}
```

Functions are executed based on value in field. For example, If value matches, function `setRed()` is fired. Then, if the value changes and the condition is met, function `setWhite()` is fired.
The result I got, after executing both functions on subscription to element is:

```
<div data-bind="dxNumberBox: dxCustomCalc" class="dx-numberbox is-valid-nok is-valid-onlyok">
```

The result I want to achieve, after executing both  functions is:

```
<div data-bind="dxNumberBox: dxCustomCalc" class="dx-numberbox is-valid-onlyok">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `class` binding to set a CSS class based on an observable.

You could do use it directly

```
<div data-bind="dxNumberBox: dxCustomCalc, class: dxCustomCalc.cssClass">
```

or you could apply the `class` binding as part of your `dxCustomCalc` custom binding, using `ko.applyBindingsToNode()`:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.dxNumberBox = {
  init: function(elem, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel) {
    const value = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    ko.applyBindingsToNode(elem, {class: value.cssClass}, viewModel);
  }
};

function DxNumberBox() {
  this.dxCustomCalc = {
    cssClass: ko.observable("is-required-empty")
  };
  this.setRed = () => this.dxCustomCalc.cssClass("is-valid-nok");
  this.setWhite = () => this.dxCustomCalc.cssClass("is-valid-onlyok");
  this.setEmpty = () => this.dxCustomCalc.cssClass("is-required-empty");
}

const vm = new DxNumberBox();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```css
.is-valid-nok {
  background-color: red;
}

.is-valid-onlyok {
  background-color: white;
}

.is-required-empty {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.5.1/knockout-latest.js"></script>

<button data-bind="click: setRed">Red</button>
<button data-bind="click: setWhite">White</button>
<button data-bind="click: setEmpty">Empty</button>

<div data-bind="dxNumberBox: dxCustomCalc">
  Profit Information
</div>

<hr>
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

> Functions are executed based on value in field.

Having extra methods like `.setRed()` is clunky and unnecessary. Turn `cssClass` into a computed observable that calculates a class name based on the state of the viewmodel, e.g.

```
cssClass: ko.pureComputed(() => {
  var value = self.value().trim();
  if (value == '') return 'is-required-empty';
  if (value < 0) return 'is-valid-nok';
  return 'is-valid-onlyok';
});
```